# Can't Track Outbound Links with Google Analytics's Suggested Approach

Tags: analytics, tracking, outbound

I'm doing everything described on [this Google help page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en) to try and get [culturehog.com](http://culturehog.com) to track it's outbound links, but it doesn't seem to report anything.

I copied the code as they list it and in the right places. I changed my tracking id accordingly and I'm 99.99% sure there's no conflicting code in the rest of the page.

Anyone else having this issue or have any tips on where to search for and fix errors??? Thank you!

Comment: Show us the exact code that you are using. Also how are you determining that nothing is reported?

Comment: It's all in the source code of http://culturehog.com. I put the javascript they supplied in the header and then added the javascript to a "Test Link" down at the bottom. My standard GA code is towards the bottom. I validated the HTML too and see no errors. As for the reports they say it's under "events," but nothing has been showing up when I click the link. :/ THANKS FOR YOUR RESPONSE I appreciate it!

Comment: Can you post the outbound click tracking code? Sorry, not being lazy here or anything, but the point of SO is to debug code, but you have to specify more precisely what code to debug. Also not everyone wants to click on links they know nothing about